# .Net project static code analysis through Jenkins and SonarQube

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

**What I Need -**

Dears - I am in process of creating a Jenkins Job for my .Net Solution. The solution has an ASP.NET web application project and a Winforms Project along with several other class libraries,

As a part of the Jenkins job execution, I would also want to perform Static code analysis for which I would be executing SonarQube runner as 'Pre' and 'Post' Build steps.

**What have I done so far -**

It is to be noted that, I have already installed all of the tools (Jenkins, SonarQube services) and all of the needed plugins (MSBuild, C#, Javascript, Powershell, SonarQube runner etc.,)

I could see that my job executes successfully. Build is good and SonarQube scanner also ran without any issues.

**The problem -**

Post successful build and analysis, I am seeing analysis report only for ASP.NET web application project in my SonarQube Dashboard. But I am interested only in the Winforms project.

My build is done through MSBuild.exe and I am pointing to the Solution file. Please note that the Winforms project is my Startup project. But nevertheless I could see that SonarQube runner is picking only ASP.NET project for analysis.

**My Question -**

If someone could tell me how to get the results of the Winforms project it would be great. Let me know, if I am lacking any bit of information. I can provide them.

Thanks in advance - Happy Coding !!!

EDIT - I don't have any projects in the exclusion list. Just the default test projects.

Attaching my MSBuild default exclusion list.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your winforms project is excluded from analysis. Can you make sure that the name of the project doesn't match the default exclusion pattern? (Which is basically matching anything with "test" in it)

Comment: My winforms project name doesn't have a word 'test' in it. Infact both my winforms and web app project just differ in names by the word 'win' and 'web' appended to the solution name respectively. (Eg., Solution name is SolutionA,sln then winforms project name is 'SolutionA.Win.csproj' and web app project name is 'SolutionA.Web.csproj'. This is really strange.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam I have edited the question to include MS Build settings for default exclusions. As you can see I only ignore 'test' projects.

Comment: Can you share your solution or a repro with us?